# jQuery Wrap function Divs but one

Tags: jquery, function

How do you wrap every div in jQuery but the div you are in? I assume it is the wrap function, but not sure how to manipulate it to make it wrap all but this div.

Comment: show your html . and explain your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `this` refers to a `div` element, you can use `.not()` method for excluding the element from the set and use `.wrapAll()` for wrapping other `div` elements.

```
$('div.classname').not(this).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"/>');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/
- http://api.jquery.com/wrap/
- http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: Wow same classname for the wrapper.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your html structure is, it can get complicated, depending upon the div not to be wrapped is a descendant of one of the div's to be wrapped.

Example:

```
$('div').wrapAll($('<div/>', {'class':'wrapper'})).filter(this).insertAfter('.wrapper');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/APahX/)**

If they are just siblings of the div under question then:

```
   $(this).siblings('div').wrapAll($('<div/>', {'class':'wrapper'}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each elements in same level except your current elements by

```
$('#yourElements').siblings().each(function(){ 
    $(this).wrap('<div class="wrapwrapwrap" />') 
})
```